# Вывод файлов из области DTA

Tags: ассемблер, dos

Функции 4E и 4F загружают в Data Transfer Area названия, соответственно, первого и следующего файла, удовлетворяющего маске. Опытным путем выяснил, что имена файлов загружаются в DTA по смещению 9E, хотя в книге об этом не сказано, а в исходнике к ней написано о начале имен файлов по смещению 30, но там DTA переносится в другое место.

Хочется вывести имена всех найденных файлов или сделать с ними что-нибудь еще, но вместо этого программа выводит какой-то мусор, среди которого имен файлов нет. Почему так? Печатаю строку со смещением 9E, где лежит имя найденного файла.

Кроме этого программа почему-то зацикливается. Когда найден последний файл, на следующем вызове функции `FindNext` флаг `CF` не устанавливается (`CF=1`, если ошибка или файл не найден), и переход на метку `exit` инструкцией `jc` не происходит. Почему? Какой-то баг эмулятора?

Имеют ли эти имена файлов терминирующий нуль для остановки вывода на экран?

```
.286
.model tiny
CSEG segment
org 100h

begin:
call FindFile
jc exit
call PrintFilename
nxt:
    call FindNext
    jc exit
    call PrintFilename
jmp nxt
exit:
int 20h

FindFile proc
        mov ah, 4Eh         ; Поиск файла
        xor cx, cx          ; Не ридонли, не скрытые
        mov dx, offset mask_com
        int 21h
    ret
FindFile endp

FindNext proc
        mov ah, 4Fh
        xor cx, cx
        mov dx, offset mask_com
        int 21h
    ret
FindNext endp

PrintFilename proc
        mov ah, 9
        mov dx, 9Eh
        int 21h
    ret
PrintFilename endp
mask_com db '*.com', 0
CSEG ends
end begin
```

Comment: Судя по тому, что говорит гугл, функция 4F принимает в DS:DX указатель на DTA, который вам вернул 4E, а не указатель на вашу строку с маской файла. А функция 9 печатает до знака $, а не до 0. так что либо меняйте 0 на $ и надейтесь что его нет в именах, либо выводите сами без 9 функции. И откуда вы взяли значение 9E которое перед печатью заносите в DX ума не приложу. Если уж смещение брать, то добавлять его к тому, что вернула 4E

Comment: "И откуда вы взяли значение 9E которое перед печатью заносите в DX ума не приложу" Потому что по этому адресу расположена строка в дампе памяти.

Comment: Ну нельзя же так из дампа переносить. При других условиях запуска программы адрес теоретически может измениться. Надо брать то, что вернула 4E/4F и прибавлять к этому требуемое смещение. И кстати, делать процедуру ради трех строчек кода и дергать ее call - перебор. call слишком дорогая опрация

Comment: Я просто экспериментирую, а еще привычка делать функцию из всего, что используется более одного раза. А есть какая-нибудь хорошая литература по моделям памяти, формату com и PE-формату? В Танненбауме только про модели памяти, вроде.

Comment: Привычка неплохая, просто функцией можно было бы оформить целиком чтение всех файлов, правда возникает вопрос куда она должна их прочитать. Ну с com все просто, файл - просто образ памяти, фиксированно загружаемый DOS со смещением 100h, С одним сегментом. С MZ/PE конечно все сложнее. Литературу не знаю какая сейчас есть.

Answer (score 1):

по умолчанию адрес DTA DS:80h
его можно менять, посмотрите функции dos,
и после mov ah, 4Eh вам дос возвращает хэндл его надо сохранить и использовать при mov ah, 4Fh